# ImageMagick - "unable to draw image" - using SVG

Tags: php, svg, imagick

I'd like to create a vector PDF using an SVG string. But ImageMagick draw function always returns 'unable to draw image' 500 error.

```
    $image = new \Imagick();
    $draw = new \ImagickDraw();
    $draw->setVectorGraphics('<root>'.$svg.'</root>');
    $image->newImage(1052, 697, $bg);
    $image->setColorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);

    $image->setImageResolution(300,300);
    $image->setImageFormat('pdf');

    $image->drawImage($draw);

    file_put_contents('image.pdf', $image);
```

I tried with just simple drawings, not from SVG source, that didn't work either.

Hope someone can help. Thanks

My SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="1052" height="697" style="background-color: #fff" viewBox="0 0 1052 697" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.6.6</desc>
<defs></defs>
<line x1="NaN" y1="NaN" x2="NaN" y2="NaN" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(NaN NaN)"/>
<rect x="-50" y="-50" rx="0" ry="0" width="100" height="100" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(155,89,182); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(576.5 399)"/>
<polygon points="-50 50,0 -50,50 50" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(241,196,15); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(236.5 257)"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if the SVG string you have is compatible with **setVectorGraphics()**.  I used **getVectorGraphics()** with the usage example [here at php.net imagickdraw setvectorgraphics](http://php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.setvectorgraphics.php#example-3897), and using that $SVG that resulted, I was able to make your snippet work:

```
$svg = "<drawing-wand/><clip-path/><clip-units>Undefined</clip-units><decorate>None</decorate><encoding/><fill>#00000000FFFF</fill><fill-opacity>1</fill-opacity><fill-rule>Evenodd</fill-rule><font/><font-family/><font-size>12</font-size><font-stretch>Undefined</font-stretch><font-style>Undefined</font-style><font-weight>0</font-weight><gravity>Undefined</gravity><stroke>#FFFFFFFFFFFF</stroke><stroke-antialias>1</stroke-antialias><stroke-dasharray/><stroke-dashoffset>0</stroke-dashoffset><stroke-linecap>Butt</stroke-linecap><stroke-linejoin>Miter</stroke-linejoin><stroke-miterlimit>10</stroke-miterlimit><stroke-opacity>0</stroke-opacity><stroke-width>1</stroke-width><text-align>Undefined</text-align><text-antialias>1</text-antialias><text-undercolor>#000000000000</text-undercolor><vector-graphics>fill '#FFFF00000000'
circle 20,20 50,50
fill '#00000000FFFF'
circle 50,70 50,50
rectangle 50,120 80,150
</vector-graphics>";
$bg = new ImagickPixel("white");

$image = new \Imagick();
$draw = new \ImagickDraw();
$draw->setVectorGraphics("<root>$svg</root>");

$image->newImage(1052, 697, $bg);
$image->setColorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);

$image->setImageResolution(300,300);
$image->setImageFormat('pdf');

$image->drawImage($draw);

file_put_contents('image.pdf', $image);
```

Comment: I think it's not compatible. I'm passing it from fabric.js with the toSVG()
I added my svg string

Comment: Since your code snippet works, if I've answered your question, can you mark this as the solution please?

Comment: Yes, sorry. And do you know how can I convert that SVG string to the another format?

Comment: Hmm, yes, that's probably a different question.  I see that the function setVectorGraphics is still new, so we would have to find other information on what it is looking for.